# jboss 7 and eclipse indigo : weird ejb project name at deployment

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss7.x, jboss-tools

Hie all,

I indeed underline to points.
I have been trying jboss 7 + jboss tools (3.3).

- When I tried to deploy an ejb project on jboss6. Nothing happend. I thus added an ejb-jar.xml file to my project and deployment occured. Strange, as the deployment descriptor is supposed to be optional since ejb3.0 (and is optional with helios+ jbosstools 3.2).
- More problematic and unsolved until now, when I create a project and try to deploy on jboss 7, the project name, for instance, "testejb" is deployed as "testejbnull" (even with the ejb-jar.xml file set) :
  java:global/testejbnull/TestBean!test.ejb.TestBeanLocal
  java:app/testejbnull/TestBean!test.ejb.TestBeanLocal
  java:module/TestBean!test.ejb.TestBeanLocal
  java:global/testejbnull/TestBean
  java:app/testejbnull/TestBean
  java:module/TestBean

Well, weird, but when I try to lookup from my Servlet (by the mean of a good old InitialContext + lookup), I got :
10:14:07,681 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name 'TestBean!test.ejb.TestBeanLocal' not found in context ''

..Whatever the name I look up for (i.e. TestBean, TestBean!...., java:app/...).

I work on ubuntu, one of my colleagues tried on windows 7 and had the same result.

Is this a classical problem? How may we solve it?

For the moment I decided to keep Jboss6 + helios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the "null" issues too, it's been fixed in milestone 4

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-10106

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-9711

Answer (score 1):

You obviously bumped into a bug witht he "null" in the naming.

May I suggest you visit http://community.jboss.org/en/tools?view=discussions and speak up there and we can help figure out what problem you got with the milestone tools.